React native build crashed in test flight
React native version
"react-native": "^0.75.1"
Xcode Version 16.0
Mac os version 15.1
Build got crashed after the splash screen in testflight
it is working fine in the development mode
I tried to run my app in release version facing the crash with below logs
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevMenu' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["UIManager","PlatformConstants","DeviceInfo","RNGestureHandlerModule","I18nManager","RNCAsyncStorage","NativeAnimatedModule","SourceCode","BlobModule"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceObserverCxx","NativePerformanceCxx","NativeReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","PlatformLocalStorage","RNC_AsyncSQLiteDBStorage","SoundManager","DevMenu"]}, js engine: hermes', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevMenu' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native..., stack:
invariant@1784:25
getEnforcing@2585:27
anonymous@288331:67
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@288289:58
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@288264:25
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@285895:52
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@285813:66
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@285784:65
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@58732:60
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@96:37
metroRequire@38:91
anonymous@770:47
loadModuleImplementation@158:13
guardedLoadModule@89:46
metroRequire@38:91
global@290137:3
'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae138 _exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180087db4 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   myapp                           0x0000000100a711fc RCTFormatError + 0
3   myapp                           0x0000000100ae8628 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] + 488
4   myapp                           0x0000000100ae8e50 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1316
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804b4760 invoking + 144
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804b1ac4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 276
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804b1d5c -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
8   myapp                           0x0000000100aa6588 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 380
9   myapp                           0x0000000100aa86e8 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicEiN12_GLOBAL__N_117SchedulingContextE + 452
10  myapp                           0x0000000100aa833c ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 116
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102363ec4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236573c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236da30 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 916
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236e774 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 420
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010237b1a8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 324
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010237a604 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 488
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102e0bb74 _pthread_wqthread + 284
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102e0a934 start_wqthread + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

Are u using something like DevMenu in your code?

No im not using the DevMeny

Are you using Reactotron in your project?
I also got this same issue and found out that issue is with react-native-reactotron version "5.1.9". Check out this link. However it didn't solve my issue. Maybe I was missing something else. SO, I downgraded to version 5.1.8 and it solved the issue.
